# How to wrap an existing DOM element with a directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have an existing DOM element that has already been compiled and contains angular directives, for example

```
CurrentDirective
     function link(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
        var element = element.children()[1]; //Ex HTML: <div testElement>test</div> )
       // Wrap element now with WrapperDirective
```

Now I want to wrap it with a new directive called "WrapperDirective" .

The catch is, "WrapperDirective" needs it's "element" parameter at link time, to run this code:

```
WrapperDirective
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         var testElements = angular.element(element[0].querySelectorAll('[testElement]'));
```

The result should be similar to having this code, but it has to be dynamically created using the already compiled inner piece.

```
<WrapperDirective>
   <div testElement>test</div>  // Just example, could be anything.
</WrapperDirective>
```

Basically I need something like

```
$compile("<WrapperDirective>" + Existing DOM Element(No Recompile)+ "</WrapperDirective")
```

I know I can

```
$compile("<WrapperDirective></WrapperDirective>")
```

and then append the rest, but the link function of WrapperDirective will not get the children element that it needs.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  You are asking about a solution you are trying to come up with for some unknown problem.  It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here, without knowing what the directives are meant to do;  "Wrapping an element dynamically" isn't generally a necessary task in angular....

Comment: The problem is totally known. The element wrapper is ngDraggable. The element is mdMenu(angular-material). I'm trying to modify angular-material's menu to make the menu that pops up be draggable. Angular material builds the menu piece by creating a root element, then appending the passed in DOM element. I need the root element to be draggable. ngDraggable needs the children to find ng-draggable-handle attributes.

Comment: then that's what you should be asking about here;  That's what gives context to the problem, and gives something that people can test and try to work out a solution.

Comment: If someone tells me wrapping an element in such way is impossible, then I'd take that answer, I just wanted to know if it can be done that way. I can modify the directives in such way that they would work, but they would get more complicated.

Comment: As a workaround, I made it work by using .append() after $compile, and calling scope.$broadcast to alert the directive that the children have been appended.